# How to set Headers in request globally in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel for developing API's. i am facing one scenario i need to set headers explicitly from the code (From job class) it's not setting and my $custom object is an empty array.can anyone help me to achieve to set explicitly headers data?

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request as HttpRequest;
$req = new HttpRequest();
  foreach($data['headers'] as $key => $value){
      //$req->header($key, $value);
        $req->headers->set($key,$value);
  }
  $custom = getallheaders(); // it's empty
```

Comment: `getallheaders()` doesn't know about your `new HttpRequest` that you manually created, it only knows about the real request that initiated the code itself.

Comment: Are you trying to set headers on a request you intend to *send* to an API? Or are you trying to manipulate the *incoming* request?

Comment: @ceejayoz,At the time of queue creation i am capturing all headers ,from the captured data i want to generate new request() through code because my base controller some logic written to connect databases dynamically

Comment: @ceejayoz ,i was trying to create a new request from the code is it possible ?

Comment: Pass `$req` to your job, and have it do `$req->headers` to access them. `getallheaders` won't work for this.

Answer (score -4):

I think you can add header in `index.php` file, because when start application set your headers!

Comment: You *never* modify Laravel's `index.php`.

Comment: Why? Or you can set headers in Service Providers